# Click button and open same window again

Tags: c#, wpf

In my WPF application, I have one main window (Window.xaml). Which has a button, if user click the button we want to open same window again(Window.xaml). Once again the user clicks the same button we want to open the same window again.

so how do I open the same window again?

Comment: Do you want a new copy of that window (so you have two, three, .. copies) or re-show the current one?

Comment: i want the copy of the window

Comment: Why do you even need to open same window multiple times? Tell us what are you trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can create new instance of your current window in button click event and achieve it.

Code snippet:

```
private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var currentWindow = new Window();
        currentWindow.Show();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a new instance of the window (e.g. MainWindow class) and call the show method.

Just some pseudo code:

```
void Button_clicked()
{
    new MainWindow().Show();
}
```